# How to share data from mqtt to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mqtt, broker

I have sensor for temperature, data from this sensor is writing to online broker, but I don't know how to connect this to wordpress.

Comment: This question need a lot more detail about what you are trying to do and what you've tried/researched before asking

Answer (score 0):

Some choices.

- Implement a web service in your message broker, then write some WordPress code -- a small plugin implementing a [shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/), maybe -- to access that service using the [WP_Http](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http/) class.
  Put the shortcode into the WordPress posts or pages where you will deliver he data to your users.
- Implement a message consumer program that writes your data to a custom table in your WordPress database, then write some code to retrieve it.
- Put some Javascript in the page WordPress delivers to your user to get the data directly from your message broker.

It's hard to offer more specific advice without knowing a lot more about your project.